# Removing masked entries from an array

Tags: c#, algorithm

The task is to keep an array of objects untouched if input is *null* and, otherwise, remove the elements that are on positions specified by the input. I've got it working but I'm vastly dissatisfied with the code quality.

```
List<Stuff> stuff = new List<Stuff>{ new Stuff(1), new Stuff(2), new Stuff(3) };
String input = "5";
if(input == null)
  return stuff;    

int mask = Int32.Parse(input);
for (int i = stuff.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
  if ((mask & (int)Math.Pow(2, i)) == 0)
    stuff.RemoveAt(i);
return stuff;
```

The actual obtaining *input* and the fact that e.g. *String.Empty* will cause problems need not to be regarded. Let's assume that those are handled.

How can I make the code more efficient?
How can I make the syntax more compact and graspable?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [codereview.se].

Comment: `(int)Math.Pow(2, i)` - rather use `1 << i` - the first is a lot slower and opens you up to rounding issues (or you could use `Round` instead of casting, but that's still a lot slower) - as written, I believe 2 to the power 10, for example, could be 1023 - that would be hazardous with your code.

Comment: Is it just me, or does this code remove the elements that are *not* specified by the input?

Comment: @lc. It's not just you. That's exactly what's supposed to happen. If *null* - no masking. Otherwise, keep specified elements.

Comment: @Dukeling You're right, of course. However, since I'm going to go with *Where* approach (as in the accepted answer), I'm not sure if the bitwise shift is applicable here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of the backwards running loop, you could use Linq with the following statement.

```
stuff = stuff.Where( (iStuff, idx) => (mask & (int)Math.Pow(2, idx)) != 0 );
```

Or even cooler using bitwise shit.

```
stuff = stuff.Where((_, index) => (mask >> index & 1) == 1);
```

It uses an overload of `Where` which can access the position in the sequence, as documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). For a similar task, there is also an overload of `Select` which gives access to the index, as documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but you could make an extension method that iterates the collection and filters, returning matching elements as it goes. Repeatedly bit-shifting the mask and checking the 0th bit seems the easiest to follow - for me at least.

```
static IEnumerable<T> TakeMaskedItemsByIndex(this IEnumerable<T> collection, ulong mask)
{
    foreach (T item in collection)
    {
        if((mask & 1) == 1)
            yield return item;

        mask = mask >> 1;
    }
}
```